# Call history In Columns SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have a Table with

```
select [Caller ID] , [Call details] from [DEMO].[dbo].[calldetails]
```

[image]

want results in multiple columns like

[image]

Comment: please check the image link to understand my requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`PIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) table operator to do this:

```
SELECT 
  [Caller ID],
  [1] AS [Call Details 1],
  [2] AS [Call Details 2],
  [3] AS [Call Details 3]
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    [Caller ID], 
    [Call details],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Caller ID]
                      ORDER BY [Caller ID]) AS RN
  FROM [calldetails]
) AS t
PIVOT
(
   MAX([Call details])
   FOR RN IN([1], [2], [3])
) AS p;
```

**Note that:**

- I used a row number generated based on the `Caller ID` to group the call details into 3 columns.
- I ordered the results by `Caller ID` as I must use `ORDER BY` with `PARTITION BY`. That's why you will find the results not in the same order you are looking for.
- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df83e/1)

This will give you:

```
| Caller ID |  Call Details 1 |  Call Details 2 | Call Details 3 |
|-----------|-----------------|-----------------|----------------|
|       123 | Ordered Product | Shipped Product |   More Details |
|       125 |  product search |          (null) |         (null) |
|       234 |  product search | Ordered Product |         (null) |
```

---

If you want to do this dynamically and don't list these list of row number manually, you have to do it dynamically like this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @colnames AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(RN)
                       FROM 
               (
                 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Caller ID] 
                                          ORDER BY [Caller ID]) AS RN
                 FROM [Calldetails] 
               ) AS t
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @colnames = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(RN) + 'AS' +   
                        QUOTENAME('[Call details ' + CAST(RN AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ']')
                       FROM 
               (
                 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Caller ID] 
                                          ORDER BY [Caller ID]) AS RN
                 FROM [Calldetails]
               ) AS t
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query = 'SELECT [Caller ID], ' + @colnames +
                  ' FROM
                    (
                      SELECT
                        [Caller ID] , 
                        [Call details], 
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Caller ID] 
                                          ORDER BY [Caller ID]) AS RN
                      FROM [calldetails]
                    ) AS t
                    PIVOT
                    (
                       MAX([Call details])
                       FOR RN IN(' + @cols + ')' +
                                      ') p';

execute(@query);
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df83e/6)

Comment: Thank you Very much ..:)